# Does a group/user need permissions to the parent folder?

Tags: windows, active-directory, folder-permissions

Forgive my ignorance to the subject, I'm new to this...

Does a group/user need list object permission to a parent folder in order to access the child folder they have read/write access to?

In other words:

Example: S:\PARENT_FOLDER\CHILD_FOLDER

If I give a group/user read/write permissions to "CHILD_FOLDER" will they be able to navigate to "CHILD_FOLDER" if they do not have any permissions to "PARENT_FOLDER".

Comment: No, in general the user does not need access to the parent folder. Standard users have SeChangeNotifyPrivilege, which bypasses traverse checking. This privilege is enabled by default. Checking the parent would be forced if this privilege were disabled in or removed from the user's access token.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the reply.